# Change default contrast in ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

Say we have a factor X with 3 levels, namely, H, L and M. If I do an ANOVA in R using `lm(Y~X)` function, then the default setting is to treat H as the reference group or baseline. My question is whether there is a built-in syntax to set L as the baseline. Please note that I am aware that we can use indicator functions to achieve this goal. What I am looking for is some easy tweak of the `lm` function. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `C` function does this, for your example

```
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(c("H","L","M"), 30, rep=T), y=runif(30))
levels(dat$x)
# [1] "H" "L" "M"
lm(y ~ x, data=dat)  # "H" is base

lm(y ~ C(x, base=2), data=dat)  # use "L" as base
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `relevel` is quite simple and flexible for this sort of case, e.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(Y=1:3, X=c("H","L","M"))
lm(Y ~ X, data=transform(dat, X=relevel(X,"L") ))

#Call:
#lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = transform(dat, X = relevel(X, "L")))
# 
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           XH           XM  
#          2           -1            1
```

As per:

```
contrasts(dat$X)
#  L M
#H 0 0
#L 1 0
#M 0 1

contrasts(relevel(dat$X,"L"))
#  H M
#L 0 0
#H 1 0
#M 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
lm(Y~X, contrasts = list(X = "contr.treatment"))
```

Other options are

```
contr.sum
contr.SAS
```